# ValueError: cannot assign integer to foreign key during put request | lookup-field as foreign key subfield

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I have a model like this.

```py
class Member(BaseModel):

    objects = models.Manager()
    user = models.ForeignKey('api_backend.User', db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey('api_backend.Cluster', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And a generic api view for the same.

```py
lass MemberPutRetrieveUpdateDeleteView(PutAsCreateMixin, MultipleFieldLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = api_models.Member.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsMemberOrKickMembers]
    lookup_fields = ['user', 'cluster']

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method in ['PUT']:
            return api_serializers.PartialMemberSerializer
        return api_serializers.MemberSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        member = self.get_object()
        if member.cluster.owner == member.user:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError("cannot delete membership with this cluster as you own it.")
        return super(MemberPutRetrieveUpdateDeleteView, self).destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am currently using these mixins.

```py
class PutAsCreateMixin(object):
    """
    The following mixin class may be used in order to support PUT-as-create
    behavior for incoming requests.
    """

    def update(self, request, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object_or_none()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if instance is None:
            if not self.lookup_fields:
                lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
                lookup_value = self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]
                extra_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: lookup_value}
            else:
                # add kwargs for additional fields
                extra_kwargs = {field: self.kwargs[field] for field in self.lookup_fields if self.kwargs[field]}
            serializer.save(**extra_kwargs)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)

        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object_or_none(self):
        try:
            return self.get_object()
        except Http404:
            if self.request.method == 'PUT':
                # For PUT-as-create operation, we need to ensure that we have
                # relevant permissions, as if this was a POST request.  This
                # will either raise a PermissionDenied exception, or simply
                # return None.
                self.check_permissions(clone_request(self.request, 'POST'))
            else:
                # PATCH requests where the object does not exist should still
                # return a 404 response.
                raise


class MultipleFieldLookupMixin(object):
    """
    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
    based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()  # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if self.kwargs[field]:  # Ignore empty fields.
                filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

So, in my serializer, I have multiple lookup fields -`user` and `cluster`. Both of these are foreign keys and have their own kwargs in the url.

So my api url is like this.

```py
path('clusters/<int:cluster>/members/<int:user>/', views.MemberPutRetrieveUpdateDeleteView.as_view())
```

and I would expect a sample url to be like this:

```py
'clusters/3/members/2/'
```

where 1 is the id of the cluster and 2 is the id of the member.
So basically a put request to this url must create a member which has:

- an user foreign key of id 2
- a cluster foreign key of id 3

But when trying to create the same with the mixin, I get the following error.

```py
in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "2": "Member.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

How can I fix this error? Can someone please help me?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually very simple,
I hope this will save a lot of someone's time.

I had to change the lookup fields to the following

```py
lookup_fields = ['user_id', 'cluster_id']
```

and the url kwargs to the following

```py
'clusters/<int:cluster_id>/members/<int:user_id>/'
```

this way, django knows that only the id of the foreign key is present in the url, and not the foreign key object itself. When perform-creating with the lookup fields, everything works just as expected!